# Arquillian with Glassfish, resourcesXml property does not appear to be a valid file path

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish-4, jboss-arquillian

The goal is to run an Arquillian test with the Glassfish server, but this error occurs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The resourcesXml property does not appear to be 
a valid file path.
```

Does anyone see what is missing here?

This is how the project outline in Netbeans looks like:

[image]

This is how the folder structure in Netbeans looks like:

[image]

This is the content of `arguillian.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
            http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="resourcesXml">
                src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

And this is the content of `glassfish-resources.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 
Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false"
                      ...
                      wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="myappdatabase"/>
    <property name="User" value="someusername"/>
    <property name="Password" value="somepassword"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedatabase"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/somedatabase" 
object-type="user" pool-name="jdbc/somedatabase_pool"/>
</resources>
```

Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: hi! did you find the solution to your problem ? Same here...

Comment: Not really, but I gave up after a while and haven't tried since.

Answer (score 1):

the qualifier must be "glassfish", here is a complete example how it works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
 <engine>
    <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/arquillian</property>
 </engine> 
 <container default="true" qualifier="glassfish">
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml</property>
        <property name="bindHttpPort">8083</property>
    </configuration>
 </container>
</arquillian>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it seems that only an absolute path is accepted. I solved it by resource filtering (similar to Slim's answer):

**pom.xml**

```
<testResources>
     <testResource>
         <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<property name="resourcesXml">
    ${basedir}/src/test/resources/glassfish-resources.xml
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in the pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <arquillianResourcesXml>
                ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
            </arquillianResourcesXml>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and in the arquillian.xml file :

```
<property name="resourcesXml">${arquillianResourcesXml}</property>
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out correct value of resourcesXml property by looking into the console log of maven. There is an line which says:

> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   ...\src\test\resources-glassfish-embedded

Check existence of this folder on your filesystem. In my case I have to add one additional resources in resourcesXML value like:

```
src/test/resources/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
```

Comment: Do not forget to change the value on both places - arquillian.xml and pom.xml